# Initializing an object in Perl

Tags: perl, memory, oop, package

So, i'm a bit of a perl newb. Although I had something much more complicated going, i all of a sudden hit a roadblock and cannot figure out wtf is wrong with the code. I've simplified it so greatly that it's only a very small fragment of code.

Test.pl

```
package Test;

sub new {
  my ($class) = shift;
  my $self = {
    _attr => "asdfa"
  };
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
}
sub log {
  print "\nAccessed via class: ".$self->{_attr};
}
```

process.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
do "Test.pl";
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my($test) = new Test();
$test->log;
print "\nAccessed via main: ".$test->{_attr};
```

I run process.pl and I get the following output

> Accessed via class:
>   Accessed via main: asdfa

I also get the warning

> Use of uninitialized value in
>   concatenation (.) or string at Test.pl
>   line 12 (#1)
>       (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
>       defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
>       To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.

So the problem is that $self is actually undefined. Why, I have no idea. Is this not the way to initialize an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object instance is passed as the first argument to the method. The usual thing to do is to store it in a variable called `$self`, but perl doesn't set this up for you, you must do it yourself:

```
sub log {
  my $self = shift;
  print "\nAccessed via class: ".$self->{_attr};
}
```

Note that although you have defined `strict` and `warnings` in your main code, you haven't in `test.pl` which means that `$self` was silently created with an undefined value rather than throwing a compile error for using an undeclared variable.

Furthermore, I would advise you to put `package Test` into a file called `Test.pm`, add a true statement `1;` on its own at the end of the file, and call it by saying `use Test;` instead of `do "test.pl"`. It's a much cleaner way to write modular code in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but you've got some serious problems with your code.

- Put your object definitions in files ending in `.pm` not `.pl`
- `use` modules instead of `do`ing libraries.
- Indirect object notation can lead to bugs, it is best to avoid using it.

I took the liberty of rewriting your code with the small changes needed to fix the issues.

First in `MyTest.pm`:

```
package MyTest;  # Changed name to avoid name conflicts.
use strict;      # Always
use warnings;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  # Removed parens on $class, they put the assignment of shift's 
  # result into list context (which had no effect on the result, 
  # but it is also unnecessary).

  my %defaults = ( attr => 'asdfa' );
  my %args = %defaults, @_;  
  # Assigns arguments and default values to %args, actual named 
  # args will override keys in defaults where they match;      

  my $self = {};      

  bless $self, $class;

  while( my ($attr, $value) = each %args ) {
    $self->$attr($value); # Initialize each attribute in named arg hash.
  }

  return $self;
}

sub attr {
    my $self = shift;
    if( @_ ) {
      $self->{_attr} = shift;
    }

    return $self->{attr}
}    

sub log {
  my $self = shift;  # Get invocant
  print "Accessed via class: ", $self->attr, "\n";  
}
```

process.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use MyTest;

my $test = MyTest->new();  # Direct call of object constructor

$test->log;

print "Accessed via main: $test->{_attr}\n";  # Violating encapsulation 
                                              # is generally a bad idea.
```

If you are doing heavy OOP, consider learning to use [Moose](http://moose.perl.org). Moose is a powerful, ultra-modern object system for Perl that adds powerful capabilities and reduces boilerplate code.

If you want to learn "classical" Perl OOP, the tutorials in the perldoc ([perlboot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html), [perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html), [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html), [perlbot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlbot.html) and [perltooc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltooc.html)) are pretty good.  If you want to get really deep into it, [Damian Conway's Object Oriented Perl](http://www.manning.com/conway/) is a fantastic book.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to thoroughly explain everything daotoad. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in the sub log :

```
sub log{
    my $self = shift;
    print "\nAccessed via class: ".$self->{_attr};
}
```